# How to get tvOS simulator to show as available simulator option?

Tags: xcode, tvos

Under 'build settings', I've changed my base SDK to tvOS, and my 'supported platforms' to tvOS.

[image: supported platforms project setting]

I've also added a tvOS as a simulator (see screenshot):

[image: added tvOS simulator]

Nevertheless, my dropdown still doesn't show the tvOS simulator as an option. What am I doing wrong?

[image: no tvOS simulator in the list]

Comment: did you already try quitting and restarting Xcode?  sometimes my simulators disappear and only return on a restart of Xcode...

Comment: I did unfortunately.  Force quit and reopened to no avail, thank you for the suggestion though.